# PainterlyPack "Biome Compliant" Vines just showing up as white

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just downloaded a customized PainterlyPack for Minecraft, and have chosen a lot of "biome compliant" options. The thing is, they all show up as just white. I have patched with MCPatcher, per Painterly's suggestion, but everything is still just white.

What have I done wrong? I didn't find anything Googling or reading through Painterly's website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which grass shader are you using for the texture pack? Seems to me like its missing and all the biomes just get white as their foliage color. Go into the texture pack folder, then the `misc` folder, and check to make sure that `grasscolor.png` is there and is not blank (or all white).

The original looks like this, so yours should be something like it: 
[image]

If it's upside-down, that's a problem.

Comment: You had it; my problem was that I hadn't selected a grass shader, like an idiot. Derptastic.